# How to add file and other inputs in a POST api into swagger properly?

Tags: node.js, api, swagger, nestjs

I am trying to create swagger documentation for a file upload API with NestJS.

This is what I currently have in my controller:

```
@ApiTags('files')
@Controller('files')
export class FilesController {

    @ApiConsumes('multipart/form-data')
    @ApiCreatedResponse({description: "This api creates a file in the system"})
    @Post('upload')
    @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
    uploadFile(@UploadedFile() file, @Body() fileInfo: UploadFileDto) {
        console.log(file);
        console.log(fileInfo);  
    }
}
```

and in my DTO file:

```
import { IsString } from 'class-validator'
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger'

export class UploadFileDto {
    @IsString()
    communityName: string

    @IsString()
    type: string

    @ApiProperty({type:"file"})
    file: any;
}
```

This way, it shows everything in swagger (and works) properly. However, as you can see there is a redundant "file" variable in my DTO class and function variable. If I remove the "file" attribute from the DTO, then the swagger UI doesn't recognize this parameter as the file input. If I remove it from the function parameter, then it shows up in swagger UI but the controller doesn't receive the uploaded file. Is there a way to correct this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you try to remove file from the dto, and instead add the `@ApiImplicitFile` decorator to your controller ? I would see this as the correct approach.

Comment: @ApiImplicitFile is not supported in v 4 swagger.

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered the same problem and thanks to you, I actually solved my issue.

My controller looks as following

```
@Controller('files')
@ApiTags('files')
export class FilesController
{
    @Post('import')
    @ApiConsumes("multipart/form-data")
    @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file',
        {
            storage: diskStorage({
                destination: './tmp', 
                filename: (req, file, cb) => {
                    const randomName = Array(32).fill(null).map(() => (Math.round(Math.random() * 16)).toString(16)).join('')
                    return cb(null, `${randomName}${extname(file.originalname)}`)
                }
            })
        }
    ))
    async upload(
        @Body() uploadDto: UploadDto,
        @UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File
    ): Promise<void>
    {
        console.log(importDto);
        console.log(file);
    }
}
```

And my DTO

```
import { IsString } from 'class-validator';
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';

export class ImportDto {

    @IsString()
    name: string;

    @ApiProperty({ type:'string', format:'binary' })
    file: any;
}
```

Notice the only real change is in the `@ApiProperty()` in the DTO. That did the trick.

Comment: You are still using two parameters: One in the function and one in the DTO which is what I had to do to make swagger show the file input. The point is to avoid this redundant variable in the DTO and make the swagger show the file input only by specifying the function parameter.

Comment: Yes, correct. It's an unnecessary hassle, but a trade off I'm okay with. I haven't found away around it.